# How to change position of a block in a region?

Tags: blocks, theming

I just added a block to the 'content' region. It shows up at the bottom of this region. How do I do to move it to the top of this region?

I'm using the Drupal default theme: Garland

thanks

Comment: Do you have permission to manage blocks? Check it on 'admin/build/block'. Each block entry has weight select box or drag and arrange facility to do so.

Comment: Detail blog : http://goo.gl/kD3TZu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's showing up below the page content (and you want it above), you'll need to add a new region. It's recommended to copy Garland and rename it as your own custom theme in sites/all/themes.

In the .info file, add a new region. e.g.:

```
regions[content_upper] = "content upper"
```

In the page template file, place that region just above $content.

```
<?php print $content_upper; ?>
<?php print $content; ?>
```

Then place the block in "content upper"

Comment: thanks, works! I just needed to add all the regions. Otherwise the old regions get deleted.